# Apache suExec is not working in Plesk 11 [Still using www-data default user]

Tags: php, apache, webserver, plesk, suexec

I just performed a migration from server to server using Plesk migration tool, Every thing works fine, websites, databases, emails setting, redirections... everything.

But, the only problem is that all websites I've transferred from my old server are running within `www-data` user even if I've this in Apache config file of each one of this websites :

```
<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup "pingagency" "psacln"
</IfModule>
```

When I've performed the migration, Plesk have created a new subscription (webspace) with my old server name, beside default one that I've created in the beginning of the installation of Plesk in this new server. In this one (default subscription) Every thing works fine and Apache doesn't use `www-data` and that is confusing me.

What can be the difference between this two subscriptions? Why is it working in one subscription and not in the other?

I wonder to know if is it possible for me to force Apache to use suExec to choose the correct user to run my PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login your plesk server >> domain >> Hosting Settings and check "PHP support (Run PHP as)", If you select FastCGI, then your all cgi scripts will be run under domain user. Please compare that setting with your both subscriptions.